# How to Convert DataSet to User Object in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
// GetUserByUsername
public DataSet GetUserByUsername(string Username)
{
    User _user = null;
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DBHelper.UserMethod("GetUsername"),con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);                
    }
    return ds;
}
```

In my above method return type is `DataSet`, here my dout is if I change the `DataType` to User then how to Convert that DataSet ds to User let me show you.

For example:

```
// GetUserByUsername
public User GetUserByUsername(string Username)
{
    User _user = null;
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DBHelper.UserMethod("GetUsername"),con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);                
    }
    return (User)ds;
}
```

Can I use in this way or is their any other way can I use instead of `DataSet, DataTable`?

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment because it doesn't directly answer the question as asked. I wouldn't use a DataSet, I'd use a DataReader. Also I wouldn't convert the DataReader to a data object by hand, I'd use Dapper. https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#execute-a-query-and-map-the-results-to-a-strongly-typed-list

Comment: what do you expect? Only a username like a string? Then sth. like this would be the easiest way:.  `return ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Username").ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to build the User obj by parsing the results yourself go for the automapper lib OR there is a such a thing as strongly type datasets (IE define a set AS User). Its been a long time since I've done that but this will get you started
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(v=vs.110).aspx